# Fetch local ressource from distant server

Tags: javascript, server, localhost, fetch, local

**Let me explain the situation :**

I have a local application that generate a local server (localhost with port) where I can have informations. I also have a distant VPS with a web application running on it. And my goal is to get informations from the local server to use them in my web application.

Any ideas how to do that ? I precise that I can't modify the local server/application because it's not mine.

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: @RobBailey Just some text to parse in my web application

Comment: A more detailed and clear explanation would be helpful to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. Anyway, I assume that, you want to access your local files from a remote server, but you can't configure that remote server. If that's the case, I will be able to help.

Comment: @knoop Yeah that's basically what I need to do.
Basically what I want is to use fetch api on my vps to fetch a localhost web page (with this or another method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is made exactly for that: exposing local servers to the public internet. Let's say your server is running on `http://localhost:3000`. You can run `ngrok http 3000` and your server will also be accessible at an address like `(http|https)://1234abcd.ngrok.io`.

Ngrok has a free plan that is really free and subscriptionless that is pretty powerful, allowing 8hr/day and 60 requests/mn (if I remember correctly), so it's pretty awesome for advanced web application prototyping.

You can then upgrade to a paid plan, but at this point you'd rather host your local server on the internet instead. Then I'd recommend [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for its simplicity and extensive dev doc.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, thanks :) However I need one request every 20ms x)

Comment: Cool! Why on earth would you need one request every 20ms? x) But hey that's another subject